# Unable to restore a layer of class TextVectorization - Text Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, text-classification

System information
Google Colab

When I run the example provided by official tensorflow basic text classification, everything runs fine until the model save, but when I load the model it gives me this error.

> RuntimeError: Unable to restore a layer of class TextVectorization. Layers of class TextVectorization require that the class be provided to the model loading code, either by registering the class using @keras.utils.register_keras_serializable on the class def and including that file in your program, or by passing the class in a keras.utils.CustomObjectScope that wraps this load call.

Expected Behavior: Model should be loaded successfully and process the raw input

https://colab.research.google.com/gist/amahendrakar/8b65a688dc87ce9ca07ffb0ce50b84c7/44199.ipynb#scrollTo=fEjmSrKIqiiM

Example Link: https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/keras/text_classification

Comment: My issue is, I made a model and did tokenization and padding on the data and saved the model. Now when I use the saved model, I have to again tokenized and pad the input before saved model can make prediction. This process is taking 1.05 seconds per prediction and only tokenization and padding are taking 0.95 seconds which is making system really slow. I want to add this tokenization and padding in model layer somehow to make processing faster for savedmodel.

Comment: Can you try to add the decorator `@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()` to the function `custom_standardization()`. Thanks !

Comment: It does work when you saved and load the model in the same notebook. But as soon as you load this model in a new notebook, the error comes up again.

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this error message (`RuntimeError: Unable to restore a layer of class TextVectorization. [...]`) when I implemented (and customized) the code from the "Basic Text Classification" tutorial.

Instead of running the code in a notebook, I have two scripts, one for building, training and saving the model and the other one for loading it and making predictions. (Thus, the error does not seem to be limited to Google Colab).

This is what I had to do (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45231):

First, I added this line in the first script before the function definition and built, trained and saved the model again:

```
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
def custom_standardization(input_data):
[...]

# Save model as SavedModel
export_model.save(model_path, save_format='tf')
```

Secondly, I also had to add the same line and the whole function definition in the second script to make sure that it works if I restart(!) ipython (where I currently run the scripts) and only run the second script:

```
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
def custom_standardization(input_data):
      lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
      stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />', ' ')
      return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html,
                                    '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation),
                                    '')
[...]
# Load model
reloaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
# Make predictions
predictions = reloaded_model.predict(examples)
```

Note: If I run the second script without restarting ipython after running the first script, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Custom>custom_standardization has already been registered [...]
```

Alternatively, you can just use the default standardization method in the vectorizer layer when building the model:

```
vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
        standardize="lower_and_strip_punctuation",
        max_tokens=max_features,
        output_mode='int',
        output_sequence_length=sequence_length)
```

Comment: Thanks. It wa actually tricky to figure out to define this function in deserialization as well

Answer (score 1):

I got something working as Hassan describes it, I think. Not sure it's the right way, but it seems to work for me...

- I define, train, and archive the model in one notebook
- I un-archive it, load it, and use it for predictions from another notebook.

See here: https://github.com/OlivierLD/oliv-ai/tree/master/JupyterNotebooks/tf-tutorials/sentiment-analysis

Comment: Please post your physical code instead of a link.

Comment: Why do we need custom_standardization again when loading the model? Typically raw input has to be used for prediction. We only preprocess while training. Maybe elaborate your answer a bit in details? Thank you

Comment: That's a good question Hassan. As I said in my first post, I'm not sure it's the right way!
This is just the way I got it to work, nothing more...
I wish someone from TensorFlow/Keras could provide some guidance here...