# error when saving a keras model with custom functions and loading it to a new notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I tried to save and load my keras model. It can load in the same workbook but runs into error when i load the model in a new notebook. The model has a Textvectorization layer and custom standardization for "standardize" parameter. First I register the custom function:

```
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
def custom_standardization(input_data):
   text = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
   ...
   ...
   return text
```

Then I define the Textvectorization layer:

```
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
                standardize=custom_standardization,
                max_tokens = 1000,
                output_mode ="int",
                output_sequence_length = 30)
```

next I build the model:

```
model_FFN = tf.keras.Sequential ([
    vectorize_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim = len(vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()),
        output_dim = 16,
        mask_zero=True),
    GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    Dense(1)
])
```

after fitting the model I save it:

```
model_FFN.compile (
            optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
            loss =loss,
            metrics=metrics)

history = model_FFN.fit(train_ds_raw,epochs =epoch,validation_data=val_ds_raw)

modelFileName = 'models/saved_model'
model_FFN.save(modelFileName)
```

However, when I try to load the saved model in a new notebook, I receive the following error:

```
modelFileName = 'models/saved_model'
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model(modelFileName)
```

error:
ValueError: Unkown value for `standardize` argument of layer TextVectorization. If restoring a model and `standardize` is a custom callable, please ensure the callable is registered as a custom object. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details. Allowed values are: `None`, a `Callable`, or one of the following values: ('lower_and_strip_punctuation', 'lower', 'strip_punctuation'). Received: Custom>custom_standardization

Could someone please take a look and see what is the issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is still a problem without a solution, according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45231).

I suspect that `TextVectorization` is not fully serializable, and this is the problem. So even if the function `custom_standardization` is registered and passed as an argument to the layer `TextVectorization`, then it still turns out to be needed within the codebase for the model to run. Which is a bit of a contradiction.

If you take a look inside the issue you can see that someone proposes a "workaround" but that involves copying the `custom_standardization` function inside the new notebook.
If you're okay with this, then this should work. Otherwise I guess you could look from time to time to the [new issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16029) that is still open for the Keras team.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you are missing an Input layer before the `vectorize_layer` in your sequential model. Secondly, to solve your error you have to re-define the `custom_standardization` function again before loading your model to avoid RuntimeError: Unable to restore a layer of class TextVectorization.
Here are links to where I found this workaround:

[1] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45231#issuecomment-799268188

[2] [Unable to restore a layer of class TextVectorization - Text Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050132/unable-to-restore-a-layer-of-class-textvectorization-text-classification)